# Splitting a list, the most simple way

Tags: python, split

I am sort of a beginner, and have this code:

```
a = input("Insert codes here ")
b = a.split(", ")
```

I want to further this by splitting the list into groups by the `-` symbol, but the following code I thought should work, but it didn't:

```
c = b.split("-")
```

Does anyone have a simple solution that can do the same thing as the `.split()` command can do?

Comment: Can you share what your input, code and output are?

Comment: `b` is a list of things split by the comma. So you need to do the split on elements of `b`. What do you want the final result to be?

Comment: c = [d.split('-') for d in b]

Comment: @tdelaney my vision for the project, which is a code-based music composer, is to have a codes that the user enters that are separated by commas, and there are two parts to the code, separated by a dash, the first being the duration, and the second the pitch. an example code is this: |.-C3, . I want to have the different codes separated to distinguish the notes from each other. I want the program to read what the pitch is and what the duration is, and give an output(s) based on the data, so the notes can get formatted to the staff. Also, sorry for not responding immediately, as I was off my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, you just need to split *each element* of `b`. Use a list comprehension:

```
c = [s.split("-") for s in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a single flat list at the end, a regular expression will wotk:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"\s*(?:,|\-)\s*", "this, is - a thing, to split")
['this', 'is', 'a thing', 'to split']
```

The thing to split is `\s*` (any leading space), `(?:,|\-)` (a non-capturing group of the union of split characters) and `\s*` (any trailing space).

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way for changing You could create a list of strings to split the input like this:

```
user_input = input("Insert codes here ")
str_split_list = [", ", "-", "example"]

input_list = [user_input]
for str_split in str_split_list:
    new_input_list = []
    for user_input in input_list:
        new_input_list += user_input.split(str_split)
    input_list = new_input_list

print(input_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

split() method splits the given string into a list with the specified seperator.

If we modify your example,

```
a = input("Insert,codes,here")
b = a.split(",")
```

gives us a list of items from your string seperated with commas

```
b = ['Insert', 'codes', 'here']
```

The default seperator for split is whitespace.

What you might looking for is replace() method.

```
a = input("Insert,codes,here")
b = a.replace(",", "-")
```

gives us a new string, all commas replaced with "-"

```
b = "Insert-codes-here"
```

[replace() method explained](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)

[split() method explained](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)